# cPanel AutoSSL Issue (DCV)

Tags: ssl, dns, cpanel, dvcs

I am trying to get SSL to work on my domain. Normally it works smoothly, but for this one it gives the following warning:

WARN Local HTTP DCV error ([redacted].dk): The system queried for a temporary file at “http://[redacted].dk/.well-known/pki-validation/13E50C26C97DC7A98F708D60696A0B05.txt”, but the web server responded with the following error: 404 (Not Found). A DNS (Domain Name System) or web server misconfiguration may exist.

I have tried the things I could find online:

1. Making sure htaccess isn't a problem
2. Checking permissions (Even opening write to group just to see)
3. Recreating the account in WHM
4. Adding IPv6 DNS in WHM just to see.

This is using Sectigo, I tried changing to Let's Encrypt but same outcome just with their setup instead of course.

From what I can see it seems to create the .well-known and pki-validation folders smoothly and sometimes also the file although it doesn't appear to have the same name necessarily as the error.

Any information required to help solve this I will provide, I'm just uncertain what is needed.

I added the account in WHM as normal and tried running the AutoSSL which failed with the error above. I expected it to run smoothly and create the certificate.